# Condition to only run on certain days and time ranges Microsoft Flow?

Tags: power-automate

I'd like to setup a Microsoft Flow trigger in Office 365 so that if I get an email from a specific set of people after hours, or on the weekend that I'd get a notification from the app. I've got the people portion figured out, and I see they have an "equals" condition for the receive time, but how can I filter by day / time range?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before, but look into the dayOfWeek() and startOfHour() functions.
You can figure out if its a weekend using dayOfWeek(), and for the weekdays use startOfHour() to know if the time is greater than or less than your preference.

-Chris